# Why is sum of SOLR sub queries less than count of main query

Tags: java, solr, solrj

In SOLR i calculated the number of documents got for a SOLR query using solrj in Java. Then i split the query into three disjoint subsets handling the entire range of main query. Unexpectedly the sum of the sub queries didn't turn out to be equal to main query. Is there any explanation for it.

Main query :
projectid: 769 AND searchsetid: 769 AND publisheddate:[2013-10-22T01:03:33.000Z TO 2014-10-23T23:53:51.000Z] : 7222 ( No of Docs )

Sub Queries :

projectid: 769 AND searchsetid: 769 AND publisheddate:[2013-10-22T01:03:33.000Z TO 2014-03-03T01:03:32.999Z] : 2524

projectid: 769 AND searchsetid: 769 AND publisheddate:[2014-03-03T01:03:33.000Z TO 2014-03-03T17:03:32.999Z] : 3462

projectid: 769 AND searchsetid: 769 AND publisheddate:[2014-03-03T17:03:33.000Z TO 2014-10-23T23:53:51.000Z] : 1206

The sum of 2524 + 3462 + 1206 =  7192 which is not equal to 7222

Please can someone explain the reason for this phenomenon.

Comment: What is the field type of publisheddate? Could you try `publisheddate:[2013-10-22T01:03:33.000Z TO 2014-03-03T01:03:33.000Z}` as the syntax (meaning "everything up to 33.000Z") instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The field type of publisheddate is : <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/> . I tried your suggestion on all the three queries, yet the counts didn't change.

Comment: Try `projectid: 769 AND searchsetid: 769 AND (publisheddate:[2013-10-22T01:03:33.000Z TO 2014-10-23T23:53:51.000Z] NOT publisheddate:[2013-10-22T01:03:33.000Z TO 2014-03-03T01:03:32.999Z])` and similar. You will then get a sense of which sub-query is 'incorrect'. You should also be able to get the list of documents which are missing from the sum of sub-queries and examine them to maybe find the problem.